# Sum of All Messages Sent

Tags: mongodb

**Mongodb Version 2.6.9**

I'm attempting to count the total a company has been involved in a messaging interaction. I'm able to get one side of the interaction using the aggregate $group, but I've come up empty on essentially looking at the two fields and aggregating those together for each unique company ID.

The `sender_id` and `receiver_id` relate to the same company Id's.

```
{ "_id" : a, "sender_id" : 1, "receiver_id" : 2, payload: "data" }
{ "_id" : b, "sender_id" : 2, "receiver_id" : 5, payload: "data" }
{ "_id" : c, "sender_id" : 2, "receiver_id" : 4, payload: "data" }
{ "_id" : d, "sender_id" : 3, "receiver_id" : 2, payload: "data" }
{ "_id" : e, "sender_id" : 4, "receiver_id" : 1, payload: "data" }
```

Using the above data structure, I attempting to produce a result set similar to

```
{ "_id" : 1, count:  2}
{ "_id" : 2, count:  4}
{ "_id" : 3, count:  1}
{ "_id" : 4, count:  2}
{ "_id" : 5, count:  1}
```

where for example Company 2 was involved in messages a, b, c, d.

Comment: Show your aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are limited in 2.6 pipeline. You can try below pipeline.

`$group` with `$push` to create single value array for both `sender_id` and `receiver_id`.

`$project` with `$setUnion` to merge ids into single array.

`$unwind` and `$group` to count the occurrences.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "sender_id": {
            "$push": "$sender_id"
        },
        "receiver_id": {
            "$push": "$receiver_id"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "id": {
            "$setUnion": ["$sender_id", "$receiver_id"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$id"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$id",
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
})
```

You can use below pipeline for newer versions. Use `[]` to create array.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        id: ["$sender_id", "$receiver_id"]
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$id"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$id",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
})
```